# Cannot connect to mysql remote database

Tags: node.js, mysql-connector

I try to connect to a remote database using `node.js` and `mysql`:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

(async () => {
    try {
        db = await mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'jdbc:mysql://REMOTE_IP',
            port: '3306',
            user: '***',
            password: '***',
            database: '***',
        });
        console.log('DB connection established.');
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(`DB connection error: ${e}.`);
    }
})();
```

But I get in console:

```
DB connection error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND jdbc:mysql://REMOTE_IP.
```

I've tried to connect with the same details via `workbench` and I could connect.
Why doesn't this `node.js` code work?

Comment: Did you try `host: 'REMOTE_IP'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2-promise), you should only set the host name or IP address for `host`:

```js
const db = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'REMOTE_IP',
    port: '3306',
    user: '***',
    password: '***',
    database: '***',
});
```

(Note: I also added a `const` in front of the `db` variable.)